# Questions about the XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xmlserializer

It would be more helpful to me; if you do answers the below questions.

1. Is it XmlSerializer is order based?
   eg)
   My class/ XML is like below. property order changed.
   Still this do serialize/de-serialize?

   ```
      public class Movie
      {
       public string Title  { get; set; }
       public int Rating    { get; set; }
      }
   ```

   And the XML is like

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <Movie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Rating>6.9</Rating>
        <Title>Starship Troopers</Title>
     </Movie>
   ```
2. What will happen during deserialization; if my class don't have property (e.g. Title) but the xml has that element?
3. Assume I have SuperClass (A) and two SubClasses(B,C) for that Superclass(A).
   In runtime how do i determine which object i should pass in the below when i got xml         response? Since I don't know what is the RootElement (B or C) of the xml?

   ```
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(B or C)); ??
   ```

---

One **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827140/use-of-dom-sax-instead-of-xmlserializer-over-httpwebresponse)** to overcome Q2

---

Comment: XmlSerializer does not utilize/require (or guarantee?) ordering of sibling elements. This is one reason why I like it over DataContractSerializer for "things that might be changed by humans". Also, please, *one* focused question per post (that is also summarized in the title).

Comment: @pst Could you please answer my second question too?

Comment: You should look into DataContractSerializer, which is more modern and is still actively being developed. XmlSerializer is not.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I still believe that DCS is not suitable "things that might be changed by humans" (which is vague phrasing on purpose as one could argue a human editing the XML incorrectly, and doing so little as changing element order, invalidates the data) - DCS makes for simple serialization otherwise.

Comment: To my knowledge, neither is the XmlSerializer. It serializes and deserializes XML based on a schema. I've never seen it accept elements out of order, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question number 2: You will get an InvalidOperationException.

> An error occurred during deserialization. The original exception is
>   available using the InnerException property.

see here: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73.aspx)

Answer to question number 3:

The solution to your problem is to implement IXmlSerializable interface. This will allow you to control the whole serialization process. Take a look at this codeproject article - it's a very good start

see here: [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8644/XmlSerializer-and-not-expected-Inherited-Types)

Comment: My question no 3 is different from that link. It is dealing with serialisation but my case deserialisation and i dont know which subclass(root Element) i am getting?? Please help.