# Use of DOM/SAX instead of XmlSerializer over HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, dom, httpwebrequest, sax, xmlserializer

I would like to use SAX/DOM parser in this below code to read a xml in HttpWebResponse
instead of using XmlSerializer. 
Please help me how to do it?

```
  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
  request.Credentials = _cred;
  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

  XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXMLClass));
  myXMLClassObj = ser.Deserialize(response.GetResponseStream()) as MyXMLClass;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
  request.Credentials = _cred;
  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();        
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

    var elements = doc.GetElementById("myelement");

    foreach (var el in elements)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

This is an example of redirecting the response to an xmldocument and pulling some elements out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads this class properties by REST invocation
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true: Successfully loaded 
    /// false: Failed to load 
    ///  </returns>
    public bool LoadMyClass()
    {
        try
        {
            string strSubscriberURL = "http://SERVERIP/url/";

            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strSubscriberURL) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(loginUserName, password);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            //Load the XML from the Stream
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

            //Use the reflection to get all the properties of this class object and set those
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] arrPropInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < arrPropInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                string xmlname = arrPropInfo[i].Name;
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = arrPropInfo[i];
                XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(xmlname);
                String xmlValue = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < elemList.Count; j++)
                {
                    xmlValue = elemList[j].InnerText;
                }
                //TYPE Converstion :Default will be String
                Object typeCastedValue = xmlValue;
                if (propInfo.PropertyType.Name.Equals("Boolean"))
                {
                    typeCastedValue = xmlValue.Equals("true") ? true : false;
                }
                else if (propInfo.PropertyType.Name.Equals("Int32"))
                {
                    typeCastedValue = Convert.ToInt32(xmlValue);
                }
                propInfo.SetValue(this, typeCastedValue, null);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            var response = webex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            int errCode = 0;
            if (response != null)
            {
                errCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                Debug.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode + " "+ response.StatusCode.ToString());

            } 
            return false;
        }
        return true;                
    }


    public static bool sendRequest(string requestURL, HTTPRequestMethod requestMethod,
        NetworkCredential m_netCred, String xml, ErrorResponse m_objErrorResponse)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = m_netCred;
            request.Method = requestMethod.ToString();
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000;
            request.ContentLength = xml.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            Debug.WriteLine("XML: {0}", xml);
            StreamWriter postStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            postStream.Write(xml);
            postStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            //Get the confschedule ID created
            if (requestMethod == HTTPRequestMethod.POST)
            {
                HttpWebResponse webResp = response as HttpWebResponse;
                string temp = response.Headers["Location"];
                string[] parts = temp.Split('/');
                id = parts[parts.Length - 1];
            }
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            var response = webex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            int errCode = 0;
            if (response != null)
            {
                errCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                Debug.WriteLine("HTTP Status Code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
                if ((int)response.StatusCode != 500)
                {
                    m_objErrorResponse.UpdateErrorResponse(errCode.ToString(), response.StatusCode.ToString(), "");
                }
                else
                {
                    m_objErrorResponse.UpdateErrorResponse(errCode.ToString(), response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                        response.Headers.ToString().Split(':')[2]);
                }
                Debug.WriteLine(webex.Status.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(webex.Response.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());
                WebHeaderCollection col = response.Headers;
                for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(col.Get(i));
                    Debug.WriteLine(response.GetResponseHeader(col.Get(i)));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```